# Failing to change user password (Devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have this problem - I need to create page where user can change his password with providing his current password.For this page I need, for other - no.

I followed this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password - I want to use solution #3

I have created new controller and added apropriate things.

Here is my controller:

```
class EditUserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!


def edit_password
 @user = current_user
end

def update_password
 @user = User.find(current_user.id)
 if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
  # Sign in the user by passing validation in case his password changed
  #sign_in @user, :bypass => true//commented this, because when I'm entering current_password
  #redirect_to root_path         //it just redirects me to root_path
  redirect_to root_path
 else
   render "edit_password"
 end
end

end
```

**Registrations controller**

```
def update
 self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)

 params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
 params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?

 if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name]) 
  set_flash_message :notice, :updated if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
  respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
 else
  clean_up_passwords(resource)
  redirect_to :back
 end
```

end
and my code from edit_password.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" }, :method => :put) do |f| %>   
   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  ...other fields...
  <% end %>
```

and routes:

```
     match "/edit_password", to: 'edit_user#edit_password'
     put "edit_user/update_password"
```

**but when I submit form - nothing is changing. No errors, just redirecting me to**

```
      edit_user/update_password
```

How I can solve this ? What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: do you have `current_password` and `password` fields in that form?  Does your `edit_password` view check for and display errors?

Comment: Try printing `@user.errors`?  There ought to be something in there if the update failed.  The source isn't very convoluted: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#update_with_password-instance_method

Comment: I added `<% if @user.errors.any? %>...` and gave me error `undefined method errors for nil:NilClass`

Comment: `@user` is assigned the value of `User.find(current_user.id)`, and if that's evaluating to nil then your problem is with the way you're handling the logging in, or maybe your implementation of `current_user`.

Comment: @bdares, I'm using `current_user` everywhere in my application. I didn't overwrite anything in Devise connected with `current_user`

Comment: the error message doesn't lie.  `@user = User.find(current_user.id)` is valuating to `nil`, or `update_with_password` is changing the value of `@user` from a non-nil value to nil.  Which, looking at the source, isn't possible.

Comment: @bdares, I think I didn't give you enough info. I overrided update action in registrations controller. I thaught it is not related. Maybe this is reason ?